# Recommended XLIFF editor for managing translations

Tags: editor, translation, xliff, angular-i18n

I'm looking for a XLIFF editor that will allow **managing** translations;
I'm expecting it to show translation custom identifiers, marking TODOs (and completed translations) and more.

Please share your experience.

I'm already familiar with [Wikipedia's reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XLIFF#Editors), but looking for experience-based recommendations.

Comment: 2020 and the situation is still horrible. In my opinion it is a disaster that no proper editor exists, only extremely expensive online options. Not cool. Why in the world not allow for simple json translation file in addition to fancier but very impractical for normal users, xliff?

Comment: I built a [MacOS editor](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/xliff-localizer/id1604486885?mt=12) for XLIFF. It uses the latest google translation api to automatally translate your file. It's free to try and I've loved my experience developing with it :)

Answer (score 0):

SmartCAT is making waves these days.

Otherwise the OKAPI Framework has a few suggestions:
http://okapiframework.org/wiki/index.php?title=How_to_Translate_XLIFF_Documents

OmegaT might be the most common, but it's rather an editor, than a complete management tool like SmartCAT.

My favorite though is translate5:
https://www.translate5.net/
But you have to install it yourself on a server.